# Run just a certain application with a special GTK3 theme on Linux

Tags: linux, themes, gtk3

Some GTK3 themes, e.g. the default Mint-X on Linux Mint MATE 17.1, cause significant problems for Java/SWT-based applications. Is it possible to just run a certain application (here the Java/SWT-based application) with a different theme instead of having to switch the whole system to a different theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [GTK_THEME environment variable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.20/gtk-running.html):

> GTK_THEME.  If set, makes GTK+ use the named theme instead of the
>   theme that is specified by the gtk-theme-name setting. This is
>   intended mainly for easy debugging of theme issues. It is also
>   possible to specify a theme variant to load, by appending the variant
>   name with a colon, like this: `GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark`.

I don't know MATE but I guess you need to [modify your launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio) or [create your own](https://superuser.com/a/1219954).

Comment: Unfortunately, this `GTK_THEME` environment variable has no effect on our application.

Comment: @ThomasS. Are you sure it's using GTK3 then? Maybe try [GTK2_RC_FILES](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk-running.html)?